# Python Regular Expression:Optional

Tags: python, regex

In a file I have following set of data

```
FX_DETAIL_69#chf4
FX_DETAIL_75#chf1
FX_DETAIL_07#bluXCFG#chf2
FX_DETAIL_99#bluXCFG#chf9
FX_DETAIL_62#chf6
```

I have written the following regular expression in Python:

```
FX_DETAIL\_(\d+)\#(\w+)
```

How can I use the optional option to exclude value `.bluXCFG`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a greedy wildcard (`.*`) to consume everything until the last `#(\w+)`:

```
FX_DETAIL_(\d+).*#(\w+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `(?:#bluXCFG)?` to specify an optional group.

```
FX_DETAIL_(\d+)(?:#bluXCFG)?#(\w+)
```

BTW, there's no need to escape `_` and `#`, they have no special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could optionally match all that follows except a newline or the # itself till the next occurrence of # using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
FX_DETAIL_(\d+)#(?:[^#\r\n]*#)?(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c5c0B0/1)